# Return subset of union depending on parameter in generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the classic discriminated union:

```js
interface Square {
    kind: 'square';
    width: number;
}

interface Circle {
    kind: 'circle';
    radius: number;
}

interface Center {
    kind: 'center';
}


type Shape = Square | Circle | Center;
```

How can I type the following filter so that the return type is narrowed down to all `Shape` that have a `kind` in `kinds`.

```js
function filterShape(kinds: Array<Shape["type"]>, shapes: Array<Shape>): Array<?> {
  return shapes.filter((shape) => kinds.includes(shape.kind))
}
```

I tried this, but the return type (unsurprisingly) always ends up being `Array<Shape>`.

```js
function filterShape<S extends Shape>(kinds: Array<S["kind"]>, shapes: Array<Shape>): Array<S> {
```

for instance the type of `s` in the call below is `Array<Shape>`. I would like `Array<Center | Circle>`.

```js
const s = filterShape(["center", "circle"], shapes)
```

You'll find a TS playground with the above code at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoEcCucooN4BQyxyA1qACYBcyA5AM5Y4S0DcBAvgQaJLIigDCwKAgA2+IiXIhqdBCPEt2XHuGjwkyQRHVRkhEmUo1aSPW07cCYAJ4AHFKgAWcR8gC8aJrmQAfbUUJf21dPnYCGEwQBDBgAHsQZBhgMT4XNwgAHlRkCAAPSFl6NFdHAD4AChkKehoAQSgoOFscgG0AIhqOgF1ygBpkejKIOuRG5taMioBKBqaWnPKDKVwwTCgk4cz6ADoUtOhKyu3HGc9lmr3QcUwKUZOR3ZqZ87gSicXUcpVuBET6GAhiMxp8piNll42ngajQOoxsLgOhxBjCTMgOgpRBJkajYRjzHxcQZ8ZiwtBkT0Iv8QIChp5kql0iNKp1CRTBpighBeoNTqMZkA

Comment: Just to be clear: You're talking about **only** when the type of `kinds` used to call `filterShape` is a **compile-time constant**, right? Your `filterShape` implementation is relying on runtime information, which can't be used to make a compile-time decision.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you’re right, I’m satisfied with `kinds` I being a compile time constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using `Extract`:

```
function filterShape<Kinds extends Shape["kind"][]>(kinds: Kinds, shapes: Array<Shape>): Array<Extract<Shape, { kind: Kinds[number] }>> {
```

Extract all members of the union `Shape` that are assignable to type `{ kind: Kinds[number] }`.

`Kinds` is an array of kinds of shapes we want. So `Kinds[number]` gives us a union of the kinds we want.

```typescript
const s = filterShape(["center", "circle"], shapes);
//    ^−−−−−−−−− type is `(Circle | Center)[]`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoEcCucooN4BQyxyA1qACYBcyA5AM5Y4S0DcBAvgQaJLIigDCwKAgA2+IiXIhqdBCPEt2XHuGjwkyQRHVRkhEmUo1aSPW07cCYAJ4AHFKgAWcR8gC8aJrmQAfbUUJf21dPnYCGEwQBDBgAHsQZBhgMT4XNwgAHgBpSnpkCAAPSFkCjMcAbQAiGQpqgF1KhoA+AAo6+ho8soAaZHpXRy7kAEEoKDhbLIqIFoBKGnHJ6YBREsnYmaGIfrxjWW78ypBMAFsAI2gG5A4WloMpYgB6Z4ABMHoAWmAAcxB4r5AcgEHB6GBkGDkGBnChcGBMFAknZHE9kPDEUlBpl6AA6FJpaBtNrYxzzTwPTq40DiTAUCD0Ek7XF1ebzFTcBCJcEDHYjZZTbaZB5eSp4Oo0aqMbC4aocPYS5DVBSiCRyhUmJXmPjqgyK5VhaByhoRLkgHkFLwE9I7No1bVG-rKoIQRr9UkM+YEV5GAB6AH4gA)

---

Note that this only works when `kinds` is a **compile-time constant value**, as it is in your question. This would not work:

```typescript
const kinds: Shape["kind"][] = ["center", "circle"];
const s2 = filterShape(kinds, shapes);
//    ^^−−−−−−−− type is `(Square | Circle | Center)[]` (basically, `Shape[]`)
```

But with compile-time constant values, this is very handy.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)