# Return subset of union depending on class in generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is very much like [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71957014/return-subset-of-union-depending-on-parameter-in-generic-function), but this time using classes instead of plain objects.

```js
class Error1 extends Error {
    constructor(message: string, public arg1: string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class Error2 extends Error {
    constructor(message: string, public arg2: string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

type MyError = Error1 | Error2;

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any) => T;

function filterErrors<E extends MyError>(errors: MyError[], classes?: Constructor<E>[]): E[] {
  if (!classes) return errors as E[];
  return errors.filter((error) => classes.some((klass) => error instanceof klass)) as E[];
}

const e1 = new Error1("e1", "whatever");
const e2 = new Error2("e2", "whatever");
const errors = [e1, e2]
const f1 = filterErrors(errors); // OK
const f2 = filterErrors(errors, [Error1]); // OK
const f3 = filterErrors(errors, [Error1, Error2]) // Error
```

Also available in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiBO8D28CM0CmAPALhgdgCYwLLzQDeAsAFDT3TBL4Q7wCuwOKAFALYYoYAOYYAXNFbwAlvmEAaaAAd2AIxDTg0MPGGoJU2cICUlWgwuT2SjPH6CIIjMYDc5hgF9aXmrVCQSRBQAJkxcAmI4IPJqOgYmFjZObjsBIVEDNiNFFXVNbV1gzJk5U1jLBghrW3t05zc4+h8fWhwATxtoAFk20hRoAF4osnQAH2GQhtaOjGgAYWYpZJQAHgAVAD5B6HwMAHdoHgA6E51hCAkwfDbTAa21qZoAM3Z8LmlmaCfpEDx4PvgEBWsDCeCIMB6AI2PFsZAu3V60QA2gBdRT+KCCAD8EgWiQ4XFWsA2qOMElgqLMcWkT0OAEIMRBBKZ4BgcOx4PhMNEYJA4KiGvRWezOdy4Udvr8ajDorctozBEcIEgBDweABrcBQOVi-qyVhXYAYJC0zUBYymPkUlENFo0BKsTDoIa7A4A1A8ABEGFQnsUnr2AAswHgAG62T2uPyLHCYUIu-YTeDBL0YYJ+6AB4NhiNR+0x3WA7ZIn2KNMo6OJL7Or4-P4AiAyuF5h2xp7x2tS-48psoCCKJHulEtgtPADM20l9Z5wOiYyTwWhsL7A-digBwWHQA).

The error is:

```
Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
  Type 'new (message: string, arg2: string) => Error2' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: any) => Error1'.
    Property 'arg1' is missing in type 'Error2' but required in type 'Error1'.(2419)
```

I can work around it by specifying the generic parameter in the call site:

```js
const f3 = filterErrors<Error1 | Error2>(errors, [Error1, Error2])
```

But that's obviously not ideal.

PS. If I remove the extra constructor arguments in `Error1` and `Error2` (which I'm not willing to do in practice), then the error goes away, but `f3` is typed as `Error1[]` -- I'd expect `(Error1 | Error2)[]`

Comment: So what exactly do you want?

Comment: @TobiasS. That's their workaround. Remove the generics from the last call and you will see.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3y1Ew) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take over from my alt now and elaborate on my proposed solution.

Frankly, I'd like to work with constructors over instance types because `InstanceType` is a built-in and `Constructor` is not, which makes this answer a little more lean and clear.

```
type MyError = InstanceType<MyErrorConstructor>;
type MyErrorConstructor = typeof Error1 | typeof Error2;
```

And I've done just that here. A union of all the error constructors, then a union of all the instance types.

Next we change the definition of `filterErrors`:

```
function filterErrors<
  Constructors extends MyErrorConstructor = MyErrorConstructor
>(errors: MyError[], classes?: Constructors[]): InstanceType<Constructors>[] {
```

`errors` can be any list of errors, which is what we want. But `classes`, if provided, narrow down the return type of the function. Otherwise it doesn't do any narrowing because it defaults to `MyErrorConstructor`.

Now you can call it without any problems:

```
const f1 = filterErrors(errors);                   // (Error1 | Error2)[]
const f2 = filterErrors(errors, [Error1]);         // Error1[]
const f3 = filterErrors(errors, [Error1, Error2]); // (Error1 | Error2)[]
```

Unfortunately you will notice the two ugly casts I have used. At the moment I don't know any other solution that's cleaner and doesn't require casts of some sort.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-oCxlM6rZOA52u59P1ArJDRaNASrEw6CG+AwAHcXmgeAAiDCoMuKMuFgAWYDwADdbGXXH5MZhQvmiyXguWMMFq9Baw3m6321nOyGoajiZXFIPSR3En8838AUCQfb8ZPszg-t2N7bgaqd-zFMSlqhSXvO5cAMyom1bs8ziCX6+KJbBW9AA)

Comment: I believe the cast is currently unavoidable. This caveat is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67622804/3019965, and relates to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912